# 3 phase panel in shop showing weird voltage!

Tags: electrical

I had a air compressor stop working.  It was buzzing. So I checked voltage.  It’s a single phase compressor one side is getting 120v the other is reading 224v. Upon further voltage testing I found that every two breakers is reading the same.  Most of my equipment that is double pull is now not working.

Mains from the power company read a:120 B: 230 C:120

Is my panel bad?

Comment: What sort of three-phase feed do you have coming in? Are all these readings L-N?

Comment: "double pull" is not a thing except in Boston.  It's called double **pole**, but what's more accurate is double **phase** in your case.

Comment: I’m in Bakersfield California.  It’s a little country out here haha

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a feeder fuse(s) opened, measure a-b a-c and b-c , some of the measurements show voltages as they are feeding through other devices. If you measure low voltages at your main panel call your power company and tell them you have lost phases. This happens all the time in industrial sites where a fused feeder gets over loaded sometimes a short on 1 phase takes out a 2nd then the circuit breaker trips, you still have power on 1 leg so there is no breaker probably fuses at the pole.

Comment: Ab: 120 ac: 208 bc:120

Comment: Looks like 2 fuses open on the pole if a wye feed, Strange voltages come from the transformer looking like an auto transformer (single coil that is tapped) if a 2 transformer delta it could be just 1 fuse but deltas are not usually allowed in residential on this side of the pond or at least in my jurisdiction.